# Jenkins build inside container - not able to deploy maven artifact to artifactory and getting 401 unauthorized error

Tags: docker, jenkins, artifactory

We have on-prem self hosted jenkins server which is successfully running and deploying artifacts to repositories in artifactory. We also have our own self-hosted artifactory (oss version) where all our artifacts are stored.

I installed docker on jenkins server so that i can run builds inside a container and i am able to run the builds but not able to deploy from inside the container to artifactory and getting 401 (unauthorized) error.

I have successfully copied jenkin server's settings.xml (using which all other jobs are able to deploy to artifactory) inside the container and i can see my container job is picking correct user from settings.xml.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project test-project: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.poc:test-project:jar:1.2.2-20210423.123456-1 from/to snapshots (http://my.artifactory.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local): Transfer failed for http://my.artifactory.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com.poc/test-project/1.2.2-SNAPSHOT/test-project-1.2.2-20210423.123456-1.jar 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project test-project: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.poc:test-project:jar:1.2.2-20210423.123456-1 from/to snapshots (http://my.artifactory.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local): Transfer failed for http://my.artifactory.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com.poc/test-project/1.2.2-SNAPSHOT/test-project-1.2.2-20210423.123456-1.jar 401 Unauthorized
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Can anyone help me resolving this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This would be

1. Your User is locked in Artifactory (this could be checked by trying to login to the UI. It wont let you if you are locked)
2. You are not using an API key (or encrypted password if your AF allows) to authenticate with (AF doesnt allow auth with plain text passwords)
3. The user you are deploying as doesn't have write permissions to the repository (or overwrite permissions if that Artifact already exists)

Are you certain that a user is being used and Jenkins isn't trying to deploy anonymously?
If you have access to the Artifactory logs that is the quickest way to determine the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but #1 - User is not locked as i am able to deploy to artifactory using same user from non-container jenkin jobs. #2 - password is encrypted in settings.xml from where is it getting picked. #3 - this user has admin permissions. I saw in the container build job's maven debug logs (running  mvn -e -X deploy) that it is picking correct user. I tried to find in artifactory's system logs but i don't see anything there.

Comment: TBH if they have admin and are being used then they couldnt get a 401 :) You could look in the AF logs for `2021-04-23T08:00:48.703Z [1e6ffb9br63e29w] [DENIED LOGIN] for client : NA / XX.XX.XX.X.` Mainly for anything with DENIED LOGIN in that has your IP.  That would narrow down that the user is being used for sure. Also look for `[DENIED DEPLOY]` (both the in access log)